# Why is ajax request submitting 'none' for value of dom element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I have a simple input box in a form the value of which I'm trying to send to django via Ajax post, but I'm getting a 500 error `ValueError at /rest/
Cannot use None as a query value`

```
<form onsubmit="return false;">
{% csrf_token %}
   Search:<input type="text" name="artist" id="artist" />
    <button class="updateButton" onclick="createlist()">submit</button>
</form>

<script>

function createlist(){
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/rest/",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{ csrf_token }}",
        artist: $('#artist').val() 
    },
    success: function(data){
        $('body').append(data.results);
    }
});
}
</script>
```

View:

```
def rest(request):

    artistname = request.POST.get("artist")   # <- problem here?
    response_data = {}

    query_results = Art.objects.filter(artist__contains=artistname)
    response_data['results'] = query_results
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")
```

When I check the headers under `Form Data` it shows `artist: da vinci` which is what I typed in. Where is the train getting derailed?

Comment: Tried this `request.POST.get("artist", "")` ?

Comment: Yes. The problem seems to be that I'm sending json to the Django view. So django is seeing `{"csrfmiddlewaretoken": "token", "artist": "da vinci"}`

Comment: Actually I have no idea what the problem is.

Comment: I guess it's the bug with the version of the Django.

Comment: It works when I just use the form to submit it, but for some reason it won't work when I try with ajax.

Comment: have you checked that the csrf token is recieved correctly by Django?

Comment: Owh funny note: If I copy your example it works for me

Comment: It works for you? Something must be wrong with my setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. My app/urls.py file was sending the url to the wrong function. I thought the `/rest/` url was going to the `views.rest` function, but for some reason `/rest/` was being sent to `views.get_search_entry` which does something completely different with post requests.

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from myapp import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.get_search_entry, name='get_search_entry'),
    url(r'^results/', views.get_search_entry, name='result'),
    url(r'^rest/', views.rest, name='rest'),
)
```

Then I had to serialize the queryset before dumping to json to send over the wire.

Answer (score 3):

copy, pasted your code and worked for me.

You can try and changing the way you send the POST request.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/rest/",
  dataType: "json",
  data: {artist: $('#artist').val() },
  headers: {
    'X-CSRFTOKEN': "{{ csrf_token }}",
  },
  success: function(data){
    $('body').append(data.results);
  }
});
```